# How set ajax data to Bootbox dialog?

Tags: ajax, bootbox

How can i set data from ajax to bootbox dialog? Or I need use jquery ui dialog, when need to set some data?

this code not working

```
bootbox.dialog({
        message: data,
        title: "Custom title",
        buttons: {
        success: {
                label: "Success!",
                className: "btn-success",
            },
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please provide more context, and also share what kind of error you get.

Answer (score 36):

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    success: function(data) {
        bootbox.dialog({
            message: data,
            title: "Custom title",
            buttons: {
                success: {
                    label: "Success!",
                    className: "btn-success",
                },
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: how can I use loop inside message ?

Comment: @Sulemankhan you can't use loop inside `message`, but you can loop through your `data` before calling `bootbox`, in the `success` callback